# Ember Need data from one promise in the model for another query in model()

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So the model for this app for all routes is set up like this:

```
  model(params) {
    let config = this.get('store').findRecord(params.config_type, params.config_id);
    let c = Ember.RSVP.hash({config});
    console.log('aa');
    console.log(c);
    let devices = this.get('store').findAllOfType('device', ENV.CFG_TYPE[params.config_type]);
    let licenses = this.get('store').findAll('license');

    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      configType: params.config_type,
      config: config,
      devices: devices,
      licenses: licenses
    });
  },
```

I need to change the devices query to use a secondary criteria which is held inside the config which is returned by the first query. The only problem is this isn't resolved and doesn't have the data in it.

When I log out c I see initially undefined for the _results property, then when I expand it, it shows the config object.

I realize this is because the promise isn't resolved yet, and is resolved some time in the future, but I need that data to get the right devices. I don't want to pass them as query params as these are two separate pieces of data I need.

I was thinking I could do .then() on the config line and return the Ember.RSVP.hash in there but that would return it to model() and I am not sure how I would return it from there, or if it would even return from there, or if config would now be equal to the RSVP hash and not the config promise/object.

My options are:

1. Find a way to pass it somehow from one route, which has the same config object already in the model, to this one, without using query params
2. Setup the entire model in the callback from the first query somehow (the findRecord() one)

Totally clueless on how to do it either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried, please have a look at this,

```
model(params) {
        return this.get('store').findRecord(params.config_type, params.config_id).then(resultantConfig => {
            //resultantConfig use this to get exact property which is going to be used for the below queries.
            return Ember.RSVP.hash({
                configType: params.config_type,
                config: resultantConfig,
                //findAllOfType - i am not heard of this method, i guess it would query, as you need to set condition.
                devices: this.get('store').query('device', {configType:resultantConfig.config_type}),
                licenses: this.get('store').findAll('license')
            });
        });
    }
```